# Show that $\det(A)=2^{p}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

We have a $(n×n)$-matrix $A$ with complex entries such that $\,A^{2}=3A-2I$.$~$ Show that there exists $p\in\{0,1,2,...,n\}$ such that $\det(A)=2^{p}$.
I don't know if my proof is good. I took the polynomial $G(x)=x^{2}-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$. So $A$ is a solution for $G(x)$. The $A$'s minimal polynomial divides $G(x)$ so the minimal polynomial can be $(x-1)$ or $(x-2)$.
So we will get that $\det(A)=2^{0}$ or $\det(A)=2^{n}$.

Comment: $$  A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\\0&0&2 \end{array}  \right)  $$

Comment: If the minimal polynomial is X-1 then A=I, and if the minimal polynomial is X-2, then A=2I. There are other matrices A satisfying $A^2 = 3A-2I$. However, the eigenvalues of $A$ can only be [...]

Comment: Has to do with multiplicity?

Comment: The minimal polynomial can also be $G,$ of course.

Comment: Yes now I  saw that but I figured it how I can do it. The minimal polynomial does not help here so much. While $A$ is solution to $G$, then all eigen values of $A$ are solution to $G$. The solutions of polynomial $G$ have the propriety that there exists $p=0...n$ such that the solution 2 has multiplicity p and solution 1 has multiplicity n-p. And the determinat is the product of the eigen values so $det(A)=2^{p}$ Thanks for the hint @CatalinZara !

Comment: Additional Info: If $n=2$ then for matrix $A$ then $A^2 - trace(A)A + |A|I = 0$ is the characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If initial relationship

$$A^2-3A+2I=0,\tag{1}$$

is applied to an eigenvector $V$ (with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$), one gets

$$(\lambda^2-3\lambda+2)V=0,$$

giving a quadratic equation with roots $\lambda = 2$ and $\lambda=1$, these eigenvalues being possibly multiple eigenvalues (with order $p$ and $q$ resp.).

Therefore, as the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues :

$$\det(A)=2^p1^q=2^p$$

Answer (score 1):

As a hint: try this
\begin{align} 
A^2 &= 3A-2I \\ 
A^2-I &= 3A-3I 
\end{align}
in the left side you can replace $I$ by $I^2$ in the right side factor $3$ then simplify. Can you take over?

> !c$$A^2-I^2 = 3I(A-I)\\(A-I)(A+I)=3I(A-I)\\ 
> \to 
> \\A-I=0\\ OR \\ A+I=3I \to A=2I$$